# Identity theft?

Tags: identity-theft

I recently checked my credit report through 3 different sites and everything seemed OK.  But recently I applied to finance a car and had to confirm 6-8 years of previous addresses. Two unknown addresses were listed in my home town that I have never lived at. With the credit reports/scores showing no signs of fraud activity would I be right in thinking someone has applied for a loan under my identity or something along those lines? If so how can this be?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you live in the US, it is quite normal when you are applying for a loan that the application will ask you to confirm your identity. One of these methods is to ask you which of the following addresses you have lived at, with some of them being very similar (i.e. same city, or maybe even the same street). Sometimes they will ask questions and your answer would be "None of the above." This is done to **prevent** fraudsters from applying for a loan under your identity. If you see no signs of unauthorized accounts or activities on your credit reports, and you initiated the car loan application, then you should be fine.